# JAVA: Programmatic Replacement of the JCE Policy Files

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa, jce

I'm working on a study project. For this I implemented a java application. This application requires a 8192-bit RSA encryption. To use the bit length, I need the java jce extension (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html). There fore i ask myself: Is it (legally) allowed to replace the JCE policy files during the installation of my program?

Thank you for your answers.
Best regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what country you're in. In some countries it is illegal to *import* that code. You should leave this choice up to the user. If they don't want or can't install stronger encryption, your program should use whatever is available.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. But in times of the Snowden revelations the default 2048 bit RSA encryption is not an option for me.